# JXM MXBean custom attributes

Tags: java, jmx, mbeans, mxbean

I have a problem with MXBean custom types and I am not able to handle it. This is my java structure, that involves `Map< enum, OtherThing>` attribute

**PPV and its interface**

```
public class PPV implements PPVMXBean {

   public enum EnumPV {
      PV1,
      PV2;
   }

   public static Map<EnumPV, PV> list;

   public Map<EnumPV, PV> getList() {
       return list;
   }
}

public interface PPVMXBean {
    public Map<EnumPV, PV> getList();
}
```

**PV and its interface**

```
public class PV implements PVBean {

   public enum EnumTP {
      TP1,
      TP2;
   }

   private Map<EnumTP, EnumP[]> mapP;
   private Map<EnumTP, EnumP[]> mapC;
   private Map<EnumTP, EnumP[]> mapT;
   private Map<EnumTP, EnumP[]> mapV;

   public Map<EnumTP, EnumP[]> getMapP() {
      return mapP;
   }

   public Map<EnumTP, EnumP[]> getMapC() {
      return mapC;
   }

   public Map<EnumTP, EnumP[]> getMapT() {
      return mapT;
   }

   public Map<EnumTP, EnumP[]> getMapV() {
      return mapV;
   }
}

public interface PVBean {
    public Map<EnumTP, EnumP[]> getMapP();
    public Map<EnumTP, EnumP[]> getMapC();
    public Map<EnumTP, EnumP[]> getMapT();
    public Map<EnumTP, EnumP[]> getMapV();
}
```

**EnumP**

```
public enum EnumP {
    P1(1),
    P2(2);

    private int p;

    EnumP (int pAux) {
        p = pAux;
    }    

    public int getP() {
       return p;
    }        
}
```

With all of this, I get:

```
...
Caused by: javax.management.NotCompliantMBeanException: com.example.PPVMXBean: Method com.example.PPVMXBean.getLista has parameter or return type that cannot be translated into an open type
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Method com.example.PPVMXBean.getLista has parameter or return type that cannot be translated into an open type
...
Caused by: javax.management.openmbean.OpenDataException: Cannot convert type: java.util.Map<com.example.PPV$EnumPV, com.examplePV>
...
Caused by: javax.management.openmbean.OpenDataException: Cannot convert type: class com.example.PV
...
Caused by: javax.management.openmbean.OpenDataException: Cannot convert type: java.lang.Class<?>
...
Caused by: javax.management.openmbean.OpenDataException: Cannot convert type: java.lang.Class<?>
```

What am I doing wrong? Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

When you write:

```
public interface PVBean {
    public Map<EnumTP, EnumP[]> getMapP();
    public Map<EnumTP, EnumP[]> getMapC();
    public Map<EnumTP, EnumP[]> getMapT();
    public Map<EnumTP, EnumP[]> getMapV();
}
```

... how is *EnumTP* in scope?

Comment: EnumTP is inside PV (at the top). Is that what you mean?

Comment: Interface PVBean has no information about what EnumTP is, since the only EnumTP is in the inside scope of PV.

Comment: I omitted all the imports for all the classes. PVBean has EnumTP import. Besides, the type of EnumP is 'enum' and I thought that enum type doesn't need anything else (like String or int)

Comment: Anyone with the same problem?